# Display full background image

Tags: html, css

I have the following inline css code:

```
<div class="home-hero" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/300); background-position: 100% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
```

[FiddleJs](https://jsfiddle.net/tty2pdb2/1/)

I need the image to be full width and height.

Comment: Give ` min-height:100vh;` Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803301/background-image-without-specific-height/48803368#48803368

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tty2pdb2/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE :

So i understand you want the div to have the height/width of it's background-image. Without any help from javaScript and if you can change your html, you could make the following.

Nest an `img` element inside the div that has the same img as the background image. Add to it `visibility:hidden`. Add `display:inline-block` on the div and remove other `height` and `width` styles.

This way the div will wrap around your image ( which is hidden ) and the `background-image` is the only one visible.

See snippet

```html
<div class="home-hero" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/300'); background-position: 100% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; display:inline-block">

  <img src=" https://dummyimage.com/300 " style="visibility:hidden;max-width:100%;height:auto;"" />
  
</div>
```

---

First, full width and height of what ?

Second, you set `height:100%` on div. `100%` of what ? you don't have any content.

If you want the div ( so the bgimage) to be 100% of screen, there are 2 possible solutions for this

1. Set `height:100%` on `body,html`

```css
body,html {
  height:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="home-hero" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/300'); background-position: 100% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

2. Use viewport units. Set 100vh as height for div ( vh - viewport height  )

```html
<div class="home-hero" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/300'); background-position: 100% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; height: 100vh; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

As a side note. I suggest not using inline-styles as they are very ' ugly ' and hard to maintain ( change/update/delete etc.). Use a css file instead.

Comment: Full image I mean when I say 100%

Comment: @Light_Warrior And my answer is ok for you ?

Comment: Not really, I need the image to be the full size that is the image, not 100vh, and also Ineed to keep the css inline since I use a variable to display the image in advanced custom fields in wordpress.

Comment: @Light_Warrior check the updated solution

Comment: Now it's not responsive, I need to make it work with width: 100% and height: auto

Comment: @Light_Warrior  Just add `max-width:100%;height:auto;` to the img. see updated answer